# Grammatic mistake in badge list

Tags: bug, badges, grammar

I guess there is a grammatical error in [the badge list](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges):

> [badge:Sportsmanship] Up voted 100 answers on questions where an
>   answer of yours has a positive score

Well, I am not a native speaker, but I guess it should be either "Upvoted" or "Voted up"?

Comment: True, same in Supporter badge. ("First up vote")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Upvoted" and "Voted up" would be fine, but "Up voted" is not correct. Take a look at [this question “Upvote” vs. “up vote” vs. “up-vote”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20457/upvote-vs-up-vote-vs-up-vote) at English Language & Usage.

I´ve extracted some info from the accepted answer.

> Within the nomenclature of this site, upvote seems to be the accepted term.
>
> Otherwise, you could go for up-vote or vote up **but not up vote.**

and

> **Up vote** with spaces does not work however, because it confuses the syntax of the sentence.

Comment: My up-vote goes to hyphenating it. upvote is not a word.

Comment: @Jamiec the past tense *up-voted* looks weired and i think *up-vote* looks more like a noun, while *upvote* looks more like a verb.

Comment: I personally dont see whats weird about *up-voted*, but I'm no grammar expert.

Comment: Holy cow the rules for hyphenation are.... extensive: http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp

Comment: Thanks Jehof, and thanks for linking the resource! I am glad my non-native feeling was right!