# How to include badges in posts?

Tags: support, editing-help

I remember there was some way to include badges in the post text in a similar way [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) can be, but I cannot find it in the [help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help). How can this be done?

Comment: Where would that be useful? By the way: you could link to [your badge page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/22/great-question?userid=166308) or just the [general one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/22/great-question).

Comment: I've never seen this. Perhaps it was a screenshot?

Comment: @JoachimSauer would be very useful on Meta, e.g. [in this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/219711/166308)

Comment: There's a [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100306/add-badges-to-markdown) for this, but it was never implemented from what I can see.

Comment: @Stijn, YEEEEES, that was it!! :-)

Answer (score 4):

This is not official and might be taken down any moment,  but I think you refer to this?

http://kevinx.net/labs/php/badge/badge.php?txt=My+Gold+Badge&c=g

The image source is: `http://kevinx.net/labs/php/badge/badge.php?txt=My+Gold+Badge&c=g` so you just type whatever you want and choose badge color (g for Gold, s for Silver and b for Bronze) and you get the image. To put it inside a post just use:

```
<img src="http://kevinx.net/labs/php/badge/badge.php?txt=My+Gold+Badge&c=g" />
```

Comment: Nope! It was an actual sequence, like `[tag:my tag]`. I think it was something like `[silver-badge:Sportsmanship]` or alike.

Comment: BTW is this something you just created? :) Because this is certainly not SE's, it has different font and little bit uglish blur :-)

Comment: @Tomas no such thing, maybe you saw a feature request asking for this. And no, not my own, couldn't find the creator though. (too many Kevin's here)

Comment: @Tomas yep, you most likely saw [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100306/152859).

Comment: Wow that's a nice template :) Just made a badge of my name lol

Comment: Thanks @nic never noticed the syntax changed! ;(